# New line character appended to os.popen().read() command

Tags: python, popen

I am retrieving a file through the below command:

```
fileName = os.popen('ls -t testfile.txt |head -n1').read()
```

while printing `fileName`, I see `\n` appended.

I know we can remove `\n` through replace command, but I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: I would remove the `\n` with `.strip()` to get rid of *all* trailing/leading whitespace, as you likely don't want it.  Same principle though of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *ls* command that append a new-line character to the output, you can figure it out opening a terminal and executing the command you want to run by *popen*

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there a way we can restrict this append ?

Comment: The easiast way to me is doing this in python rather than truncate the "\n" from the stdout.  Once you collect the data, instead of using replace just use range indexing (I do not know if this term is correct, I show you an example).
Let say 
data = "These are data\n"
data[:-1] means to grab data from first char to last one exluded, so in this case
data[:-1] = "These are data"

Answer (score 1):

There ***is*** a way to do it.

You can pipe the [tr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tr-command-in-unix-linux-with-examples/) command to ls, for example:

```sh
ls -A | tr '\n' ' ' | less
```

Just use the command as:

```sh
ls | tr '\n' ' ' | head n-1
```

So in your Python code you can just

```py
fileName = os.popen("ls -t testfile.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | head n-1").read()[:-1]
```

This will replace the newline with a space character and then exclude it from the string.

Comment: not working. When added "tr" got the error,
"tr: when truncating set1, string2 must not be empty"

After correcting that, head n-1 (or) head -n1 not filtering the latest file.


Finally used without "tr" and used replace function after reading the value.

Comment: But of course, the second argument of `tr` must be a non-empty string, that's why I used an empty space character. Therefore you can just:

`fileName = os.popen("ls -t testfile.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | head n-1").read()[:-1]`